# Can we purchase multiple copies (at one go) of same product id without multiple authentication popups?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, non-renewing-subscription

We have implemented non-renewing subscriptions in an iOS app. There are different packs with different product Ids. We would like to purchase multiple quantities of the same pack / product id, by leveraging queuing, at one go.

But when we do so the authentication pop-up shows up multiple times.

For example, if we order 3 copies of the pack / product id, then the authentication popup shows up 3 times, even though the order was via a single request submission.

This obviously is very bad user experience.

Is it possible to purchase multiple quantities of the same product id but not get multiple authentication pop-ups?

Please help with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purchasing multiple consumables at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817449/purchasing-multiple-consumables-at-a-time)

Comment: This is about non-renewing subscriptions. Not about consumables.

Comment: Ah ok. Well if I could rescind my close-as-duplicate vote, I would. I don't understand the use case for purchasing more than one of a particular subscription. I think of subscriptions as non-consumables that expire -- so my understanding is that you can't specify quantity -- but could you add a little more detail as to why your users purchase multiple packs with a given product id?